# Holding function for Yahtzee game

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea how to make a holding function for my Yahtzee game. I have 6 dice, and I want to be able to hold any number of them, when I click on them, so they won't change when I execute my roll function. Additionally I want want the dice to change image when clicked.

I use an array to store whether dice are held or not.

Where I store the dice value, and whether the dice are held or not:

```js
var dice = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
var hold = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);

function rollDice() {
    if (turn<3){
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (hold[i] == 0) {
                dice[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                document.getElementById("die" + i).src = '/images/' + (dice[i]) + '.png';
            }
        }
        turn = ++turn;
        document.getElementById("rules").innerHTML = dice;
    }     
    else{
        document.getElementById("rules").innerHTML = "Ikke flere kast";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="dice">
    <img id="die0" class="dice" src="images/1.png" onclick="holdDice()">
    <img id="die1" class="dice" src="images/2.png" onclick="holdDice()">
    <img id="die2" class="dice" src="images/3.png" onclick="holdDice()">
    <img id="die3" class="dice" src="images/4.png" onclick="holdDice()">
    <img id="die4" class="dice" src="images/5.png" onclick="holdDice()">
    <img id="die5" class="dice" src="images/6.png" onclick="holdDice()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hold function is rather simple: In my HoldDice function I check to see if the die hasn't been held (0) then I set to 1 for hold, otherwise 0 to unhold it.

I also changed your inline click to a more modern addeventlistener and added the dice # as a data attribute to each image.

```js
var dice = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
var hold = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0);

function rollDice() {
    if (turn<3){
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (hold[i] == 0) {
                dice[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                document.getElementById("die" + i).src = '/images/' + (dice[i]) + '.png';
            }
        }
        turn = ++turn;
    }     
    else{
        document.getElementById("rules").innerHTML = "Ikke flere kast";
    }
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("dice");
    for(var z = 0;z<imgs.length;z++){
        imgs[z].addEventListener("click",function(){
           hold[this.dataset.index] = (hold[this.dataset.index] == 0) ? 1 : 0;                
        });
    }
```

```html
<div id="dice">
    <img id="die0" data-index="0" class="dice" src="images/1.png">
    <img id="die1" data-index="1" class="dice" src="images/2.png">
    <img id="die2" data-index="2" class="dice" src="images/3.png">
    <img id="die3" data-index="3" class="dice" src="images/4.png">
    <img id="die4" data-index="4" class="dice" src="images/5.png">
    <img id="die5" data-index="5" class="dice" src="images/6.png">
</div>
```